# css - make shadow only on top of a div tag

Tags: css

i am using the following code to make a shadow inside a div tag..

```
box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px #000 , inset 0 -10px 10px -10px #000;
```

but i get shadows on the top and bottom.. i only want the shadow to appear on top not the botton something like the following picture..

[image]

i'e been tinkering with the codes for hours but nothing... how can i do this. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
box-shadow: inset 0 10px 20px -15px #000;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S3Pt9/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete the part after the comma.

```
box-shadow: inset 0 10px 10px -10px #000;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9LzV4/

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px 0 #E3E3E3;
box-shadow:inset 0 3px 5px 0 #E3E3E3;
```

for more experiments go to [css3 generator](http://css3generator.com/)

Answer (score 1):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/resourceguru/pen/baxdr)